# Rest API Get Automation using Robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to automate a rest api `get` method using `robotframework`

In robot we have a library called `requests`. Using this we can get the data and all. My question is that to automate that api is it OK just validate the status code 200?

Or do we need to validate the entire json data?

If we must to validate the data then how to validate?

If we have one value we can validate that but if we have multiple how to validate??

Comment: Welcome to [so] where we try to help people with their programming difficulties. Writing a question that entices the community to respond is not easy. A question is also expected to have certain elements, chief among them being a code example and the observed and expected results. Another is to stick to 1 question at a time. Much of this is explained in [ask] and [help]. As for your validation approach, I think this much depends on what your requirement is and which other tests are part of the suite.

Answer (score -1):

If you are still having issues this package may help you:
https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba

For APIs it uses the requests library but with some extended methods for making calls easier and validation very simple. You can take a look at the example robot tests for help.